# Windows 7: unable to register DLL - Error Code:0X80004005

Tags: windows-7, regsvr32

When I tried to register a COM DLL,

```
regsvr32 rpcrt4.dll
```

I get the following error message:

`The module "c:\windows\system 32\"rpcrt4.dll" was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0X80070006.

How do I fix this problem? Please help.

Comment: Which error was it, 0x80070006 (as mentioned in the question body) or 0x80004005 (as mentioned in the title)?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

According to this: http://www.vistax64.com/vista-installation-setup/33219-regsvr32-error-0x80004005.html

Run it in a elevated command prompt.

Comment: I got error 80004005 trying to register a certain msmpeg2enc.dll that is found windows\system32. (Running Windows 10 build 10074) Even when running from an elevated command prompt.

Comment: Has to be the worst error message ever and the simplest fix.

Answer (score 36):

Open the start menu and type `cmd` into the search box
Hold `Ctrl + Shift` and press `Enter`

This runs the Command Prompt in Administrator mode.

Now type `regsvr32 MyComobject.dll`

Comment: IMHO that's the best anwswer. You cannot run cmd as `runas /user:Administrator cmd.exe` This will not be enough. You should use this method you explained. +1 for that

Answer (score 4):

Use following command should work on windows 7.  don't forget to enclose the dll name with full path in double quotations.

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regsvr32 "c:\dll.name"
```