# Object Library Not Registered When Adding Windows Common Controls 6.0

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, registration, ocx

I am trying to install Visual Studio 6 on a Windows 7 32bit machine.

The OS intall was from bare metal.

I followed the instructions mentioned [here](http://www.fortypoundhead.com/showcontent.asp?artid=20502) (which I have used before)

The install went fine with no errors reported but when I try to add the `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0` to the toolbox I get the "Object Library Not Registered" Error.

I tried doing a manual uninstall and reinstall of the OCX which both succeeded but I still have the same error.

I tried installing SP6 and that installed without error (and updated the OCX to a newer version) but I still have the same problem.

**EDIT:**

As mentioned below on further investigation it seems that the IE10 update breaks the MSCOMCTL.ocx. However I also think this is something to do with the order because I have another Windows 7 machine with IE10 that works fine.

Comment: While installation can you select everything and then try.

Comment: @AshReva - I am selecting the VB6, ActiveX, Data Access and Graphics features to be installed

Comment: still i just wanted you to give it a try. If possible then do otherwise i dont see any issue if you have installed correctly as per the link you gave. I had too installed it on Win7 without any issues

Comment: I am on Win7 x64 and also have this issue. But I can add `Microsoft Windows Common Controls 5.0 (SP2)`, which seems to have all the same controls under different versions. Maybe that will work for you

Comment: By the way, that is `C:\Windows\System32\mscomctl32.ocx`, which if I am not mistaken was the location of the control I used under Windows XP

Comment: @DanVerdolino - I have the same behaviour 5.0 is ok but 6 is not. It is not an option to use this version however.

Comment: @MattWilko Have you tried to use ProcessMonitor/API Monitor to find out which library(ies) is not registered, exactly?

Comment: @MattWilko you might consider looking at my answer. It is the right thing to do without uninstalling IE10.

Comment: I had two suspects - KB2687503 and the IE10 update. But I have another machine with the same updates that works fine so I couldn't quite figure it out. Anyway - your accepted answer worked for me and I'm really glad because I tried everything else before and absolutely nothing worked or had any kind of effect. Thanks!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

On 32-bit machines:

```
cd C:\Windows\System32
regsvr32 mscomctl.ocx
regtlib msdatsrc.tlb
```

or on 64 bit machines:

```
cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64
regsvr32 mscomctl.ocx
regtlib msdatsrc.tlb
```

These need to be [run as administrator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5413614/3366359).

Comment: OMG. This did the trick. The solution to my problem I was so desperately looking for. Seriously - you just saved my day. Any idea what the fix actually does or how it works?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have been struggling to add "Microsoft Windows Common Controls-2 6.0 (SP4)". Now it works.

Comment: Worked for me too, but I ran regtlib from c:\Windows\system32 (32-bit Windows 7, like the orginal poster, so I don't have a SysWOW64 folder)

Comment: For those who didn't have regtlib, use this: http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Utilities/Type_Library_Registration_Utility/VB6_Register_TypeLib_Utility.asp

Comment: regtlibv12.exe can be used in place of regtlib.exe and can be found in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30139 folder, as described in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527213/how-to-register-a-legacy-typelib-tlb-on-windows-7)

Comment: First time I have ever had to use `regtlib` but it did the trick!  Thanks

Comment: I have windows 10 64 bit 
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regtlib msdatsrc.tlb
'regtlib' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this is not fixable by unregistering and registering the MSCOMCTRL.OCX like before.  I have been trying to pin down which update is the source of the problem and it looks like it's either IE10 or IE10 in combination with some other update that's causing the problem.  If I can get more time to invest in this I'll update my post but in the meantime uninstalling IE10 resolves the issue.

Comment: maybe consider updating your answer or deleting it? see my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem. VB6 Win7 64 bit and have come across a very simple solution, so I figured it would be a good idea to share it here in case it helps anyone else.

First I have tried the following with no success:

- unregistered and re-registering MSCOMCTL, MSCOMCTL2 and the barcode active X controls in every directory I could think of trying (VB98, system 32, sysWOW64, project folder.)
- Deleting working folder and getting everything again. (through source safe)
- Copying the OCX files from a machine with no problems and registering those.
- Installing service pack 6
- Installing MZ tools - it was worth a try
- Installing the distributable version of the project.
- Manually editing the vbp file (after making it writeable) to amend/remove the references and generally fiddling.
- Un-Installing VB6 and re-Installing (this I thought was a last resort) The problem was occurring on a new project and not just existing ones.

**NONE of the above worked but the following did**

```
Open VB6
New project
>Project
    >Components
        Tick the following:
            Microsoft flexigrid control 6.0 (sp6)
            Microsoft MAPI controls 6.0
            Microsoft Masked Edit Control 6.0 (sp3)
            Microsoft Tabbed Dialog Control 6.0 (sp6)
        >Apply
```

After this I could still not tick the Barcode Active X or the windows common contols 6.0 and windows common controls 2 6.0, but when I clicked apply, the message changed from unregistered, to that it was already in the project.

```
>exit the components dialog and then load project.
```

This time it worked. 
Tried the components dialog again and the missing three were now ticked. Everything seems fine now.

Answer (score 0):

...and on my 64 bit W7 machine, with VB6 installed... in DOS, as Admin, this worked to solve an OCX problem I was having with a VB6 App:

```
cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64
regsvr32 mscomctl.ocx
regtlib msdatsrc.tlb
```

YES! This solution solved the problem I had using MSCAL.OCX (The Microsoft Calendar Control) in VB6.

Thank you guys!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You Just execute the following commands in your command prompt,

For 32 bit machine,

```
cd C:\Windows\System32
regsvr32 mscomctl.ocx
regtlib msdatsrc.tlb
```

For 64 bit machine,

```
cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64
regsvr32 mscomctl.ocx
regtlib msdatsrc.tlb
```

Comment: That's awesome.. It fixed an issue for me too. I'm now able to compile the legacy VB6 app. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

You can run the tool from Microsoft in this KB http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q195353 to fix the licensing issues for earlier ActiveX controls. This worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

To overcome the issue of Win7 32bit VB6, try copying from Windows Server 2003 `C:\Windows\system32\` the files `mscomctl.ocx` and `mscomcctl.oba`.

Comment: Copying files from an earlier version of Windows will often lead to an unstable system and is not recommended.

Comment: Thank you then then from where we can get the original ones as still these file not valid for 2008R2.?   Because this is deployed to Win7 version also hence is it still making issue. I didn't get any issue deploying yet.