# "Object library not registered" when adding Microsoft Rich Textbox Control 6.0 (SP6)

Tags: vb6, ide, richtextbox, ocx

I try to add `Microsoft Rich Textbox Control 6.0 (SP6)` control via *Project -> Components...* in VB6 IDE. The control is present in the list of controls. When I tick it and click OK/Apply, I get `Object library not registered` error:

[image: VB6 IDE Object library not registered error]

Environment is Windows 7 SP1 x64 with latest updates, VB6 SP6 + KB957924. `richtx32.Ocx` is present in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\`.

I tried re-registering .ocx by running this in elevated command prompt:

```
cd c:\windows\SysWOW64
regsvr32 /u richtx32.Ocx
regsvr32 richtx32.Ocx
```

Registration completes successfully, but doesn't resolve the problem.

When I look at what's going on under the hood with [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor), the most recent suspicious call is `LoadRegTypeLib ({7c0ffab0-cd84-11d0-949a-00a0c91110ed}, 0x0001, 0x0000, LOCALE_NEUTRAL, 0x0018e82c)` that returns `TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED`.

Comment: There's a related question where I came from and that fits my problem better. It seems to have the same solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/q/15614730/828499

Comment: This solution also applies to [Object Library Not Registered When Adding Windows Common Controls 6.0][1] 
 
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614730/object-library-not-registered-when-adding-windows-common-controls-6-0

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by running the following in elevated command prompt:

```
cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
regtlib msdatsrc.tlb
```

This also helped with other older .ocx files, like Graph32.ocx and Threed32.ocx

Comment: Thanks! That actually fixed my problem with MSCOMCTL.OCX. Any deeper insight on what it does or how it works?

Comment: @Semmel It boils down to very basic COM knowledge. The root cause of the problem was that particular interface wasn't registered in a system. So obvious resolution was to register type library with description of the missing interface. That's what `regtlib` does. Try out this link if you are still confused: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366757.aspx

Comment: I encountered this same problem on a 32-bit Windows 7 machine.  The fix is the same, it's just that `regtlib` resides in **`C:\Winodws\System32`**.

Comment: If there is no `regtlib.exe` in `C:\Windows\System32`, `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regtlibv12.exe` also works.

Comment: On my windows 7 64 bit mahcine I didn't have regtlib in syswow64, but running the one in c:\windows\system32 fixed the problem.

Comment: Had the same problem loading an old VB6 project your answer worked thanks.

Comment: Thx so much for this fix! I've been banging my head for a few days now from having the same issues and trying to figure out what the heck was going on.

Comment: I had a similar issue with Threed20.ocx and Sheridan's calendar widget controls (SSCALA32.ocx). regtlib fixed the issue for me also.

Comment: Save the day for me. regtlibv12.exe msdatsrc.tlb fixed the issue for me