# Object library not registered VB 6

Tags: vb6, ocx

I am trying to open a VB project on Windows 7 64 bit version. I installed VB 6 successfully and registered the required components (.ocx) too. For the application, I use a third party tool called TX - Text Control and need to register that too using the registry server tool as follows:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64>regsvr32 tx4ole.ocx
```

Upon opening up the project, I get a bunch of errors like "Object Library not registered" even when Ive registered the component as above. Upon pressing "OK" and proceeding, it complains about the texteditor.ocx not registered. But I did register that too. I get a log message in the project directory which has the message as follows:

> Line 74: Class Tx4oleLib.TXTextControl of control txEditor was not a loaded control class.

Tried all un-registering all the components, un-installing VB6, fresh-installing using administrator and registering all the above components again with administrative privs but same result. Any idea why that would happen ?

Comment: So the regsvr32 command works? When you add that DLL to a blank project what happens?

Comment: @Rob regsvr32 command does work. If the .ocx exists, I get a DLLRegister successful message. if I type in the command itself " regsvr32 " it says that I need to provide a binary name

Comment: and if you add the component to a blank project?

Comment: Do you mind adding the project file to this so I can take a look at it. Also is the project in a version control system? I just in the last 4 months got our project at work to run on windows 7 and this is one of the problems we ran into. Anyone who opened the project before having all dlls registered needed to force latest on the project and that fixed the problem.

Comment: Also I would suggest clearing out your vb tmp files. I use this bat file almost every day at work whenever the vb6 ide crashes on me. These are the commands in the bat file `c:`, `cd \ `, and `del /s /f  vb*.tmp` it just runs through and blows away all the temp files because more often than not vb6 does not cleanup after itself.

Comment: @MaxYoung I cannot add the project file to the public forum. I wish I could. It is work specific and not my own project. :(

Comment: Yes, the project is in a version control system

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same problem and actually found two issues.  The first is "Object library not registered" issue.  I solved that using another answer on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018271/object-library-not-registered-when-adding-microsoft-rich-textbox-control-6-0).

Basically I ran the command `regtlibv12.exe msdatsrc.tlb` from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`.

The second issue was that I couldn't compile because of a missing reference.  To fix that, I clicked project->References and then unchecked all references.  I then reran the project (which failed).  Next, I added back the necessary references using project->References.  For missing references I used the browse button to find and add the missing references.