# Microsoft Common Controls missing

Tags: vba, ms-access, treeview, activex, ms-office

I got a strange issue with my new PC, running Windows 7 x64 and MS Office 2013 x64:
On my other Notebook (Windows 8.1 x64/Office 2013 x64) i've created an MS Access DB, that uses the Microsoft Treeview control Active-X.
I cannot find this control on my PC and therefore not open the DB on the PC but only on my Notebook. The MSCOMCTL.OCX was missing on my PC, so i copied it from my notebook, placed it in the SysWOW64 folder and registered it with regsvr32 (both 32 and 64 bit) but still no Treeview (same for Listview or any other VB6 Active-X control).
I've searched the net for clues and found much info, but nothing helped (including [Object Library Not Registered When Adding Windows Common Controls 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614730/object-library-not-registered-when-adding-windows-common-controls-6-0)).

When i manually add the MSCOMCTL.OCX reference to a new Access DB (by opening VBA Editor ==> Extras ==> References), the "MS Windows Common Control 6.0 (SP6)" appears in the reference list, but still no Treeview control available.

I don't know what else to do...

Any info about this are appreciated!

Comment: http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/treeview.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use a 32 bit version of Access. There is no x64 bit version of the common controls.

Comment: That's it. I've double checked and my other Notebook got Office in the 32 bit version and not 64 bit. Don't know why i missed this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add it manually to your toolbox. Just create new useform in VBA Editor, click on it, go to View==>Toolbox, then right click on empty space there, select Additional Controls, place a checkmark by Microsoft Treeview control.