# Windows 7 64bit & Visual Basic 6.0 - MSCOMCT2.OCX not registered after successful registration

Tags: vb6, registration, windows-7-x64, ocx

I successfully registered MSCOMCT2.OCX (regsvr32 MSCOMCT2.OCX)
[image]

Then i successfully registered wmnetmgr.dll (regsvr32_wmnetmgr.dll)
[image]

After that I tried to add component to Visual Basic 6 project but I've got error:

> Object library not registered.

Would you be so kind to help me please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object Library Not Registered When Adding Windows Common Controls 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614730/object-library-not-registered-when-adding-windows-common-controls-6-0)

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to play about copying .OCA files around.

[INFO: What Is an OCA file?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149429#/en-us/kb/149429)

You can't just cargo-cult your way around an improperly installed VB6.  Make sure you have a legal copy and install it elevated and such problems do not appear.

Comment: I've got legal version of Visual Basic 6 Professional as well as on machine with operation system Windows XP. There's no problem on it.