# Unable to load MSCOMCT2/MSCOMCTL in VB6 IDE using Windows 7 64bit

Tags: dll, vb6, activexobject, mscomm32, mscomct2.ocx

Hope you are well.

I've been having an absolute pain trying to load the MSCOMCT2/MSCOMCTL components in the VB6 editor.

The steps I have taken are the following:

I've successfully registered the components using regsvr32 in CMD with admin rights. Once I go to load the component that I registered, I'm given the component is not registered error.

I've even manually de-registered the components and re-registered them after restating my pc - nothing changes.

I've tried registering and referencing both components in the System32 and SysWOW64 folder.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the VB6 IDE and repeated the above to no luck.

Even when I check regedit, the components seem to be registered and de-registered when expected.

Can anyone kindly suggest a fix?

Thank you!

Comment: Time has not been kind to these components, multiple critical security updates made a mess.  Read this [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2664258), delete the .exd files.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor next.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, do you think Microsoft has disabled them in some means from even working/being registered? I've managed to manually register other legacy components without an issue.... @HansPassant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Object Library Not Registered When Adding Windows Common Controls 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614730/object-library-not-registered-when-adding-windows-common-controls-6-0)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution! 
After right clicking cmd as admin and hitting in the following:

"regsvr32 MSCOMCTL.OCX"

Type

"regtlib msdatsrc.tlb"   <--------------------

That for some reason fixed it.....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614730/object-library-not-registered-when-adding-windows-common-controls-6-0/16167559#16167559