# I'm getting error "File Not Found" when i try to export crystal report 8.5 to PDF in VB6

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports, vb6

```
Dim crp As New CRAXDRT.Application
Dim rep As CRAXDRT.Report

Set rep = crp.OpenReport(GlbRepPath + "indent_rep.RPT")

rep.ExportOptions.Reset
rep.EnableParameterPrompting = False
rep.DiscardSavedData
rep.ExportOptions.PDFExportAllPages = True

rep.RecordSelectionFormula = "{I_IndentheadT.IND_NO}='" + txtIndentNo.Text + "'"

vFileName = Left(txtIndentNo.Text, 3) + Right(txtIndentNo.Text, 6) + ".pdf"

rep.ExportOptions.DiskFileName = "d:\indent.pdf" 'App.Path & "\" & vFileName

rep.ExportOptions.DestinationType = crEDTDiskFile
rep.ExportOptions.FormatType = crEFTPortableDocFormat

rep.DisplayProgressDialog = False
rep.Export False
```

**My code is for converting crystal report to pdf from VB6. The last line gives the error "File Not Found"**

Comment: Try with different file locations or change the last code line to rep.Export True and see what happens.

Comment: Thnx Smith for your prompt response. 
I have tried both but same error.

Comment: What's the value of `GlbRepPath`? Are you sure the value ends with a backslash?

Comment: Yes it ends with backslash

Answer (score 0):

Missing file might be some of the files CR uses for PDF export.
Check if these files exist:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.0\bin\crtslv.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Crystal Decisions\2.0\bin\ExportModeller.dll
C:\WINDOWS\Crystal\crxf_pdf.dll
```

Comment: Dear Smith,I have to diff computer, one with XP & another with Win10. In both i have Crystal Report 8.5. So i dont have Crystal Decision or Crystal Folder.

Comment: I tried with Export True, but same error.

Comment: If your code works fine on Win XP and “File Not Found” error pops up on Win 10, copy the entire folder C:\WINDOWS\Crystal from Win XP to Win 10 machine and try pdf export.

Comment: Process Monitor is a great tool for troubleshooting various problems. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59463345/distributing-visio-addin-developed-in-vb6/59466130?noredirect=1#comment105141293_59466130
User your application name instead of regsvr32.exe.

Comment: When i export to pdf from Crystal Report it works, But it does not work from VB code.